# png's to ffmpeg conversion`

Tags: ffmpeg, png

I have a bunch of png images that I want to feed through ffmpeg to create a animation.

Anybody have some guidelines or ideas as to how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [FFmpeg FAQ: How do I encode single pictures into movies?](http://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#How-do-I-encode-single-pictures-into-movies_003f) Note that your images must be in sequential order starting with 1 such as *image0001.jpg*. Alternatively, you can use `cat` to feed non-numbered images to FFmpeg. See [Converting hundreds of pictures of naming style “frame_0000.jpg”, “frame_0001.jpg” into an avi?](https://superuser.com/a/370751/110524) for an example.